# Java constant is out of range

Tags: java, long-integer

I want to declare a big constant. But java shows an error, that my constant is too big for int. But I want a long constant. What to do?

```
 public static final long MAXMONEY = 1000000000000000000;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to write a long literal you need to add an `L` to the end of the number. Try

```
public static final long MAXMONEY = 1000000000000000000L;
```

I did not test, if this number is small enough for a long.

Comment: It's in range. One more zero and it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 10):

Put an `L` on the end of it.

```
public static final long MAXMONEY = 1000000000000000000L;
```

From JLS section [3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int.

And yes, this value is within range for a `long`.

There is a nice little summary of syntax for constant values [here](http://www.javaying.com/2006/12/whats-java-literal.html).

Answer (score 5):

By default all non floating point literals are treated as integers and max value of integer is `2147483647`, so `1000000000000000000` is incorrect here (it is out of integers range).

If you want to create `long` literal you need to specify it by adding `l` or `L` at the end like

```
1000000000000000000l
1000000000000000000L
```

Preferred way is to add `L` because `l` looks like `1` and cause confusion.

But if you really are going to operate on big numbers consider using `BinInteger` or `BigDecimal` classes to avoid [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). You can instantiate them with

```
new BigInteger("1000000000000000000");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need VERY big numbers, you can define several variables for one number.